# How to see beyond last 10 updates in case imports in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

How can I see more than 10 case imports in the "recent uploads" window in the CommCare import tool?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the recent window tool will only show the last 10 responses. I unfortunately have not found a way to expand this further.

If you are trying to identify cases created via the case importer, you could perform a case export and choose to add the properties "opened_by_username" and "opened_date". Since the case import was done on CommCareHQ, it would likely have been done by an admin or someone with data management privileges on the space. You could use the "opened_by_username" and "opened_date" properties to identify cases created in rapid succession by the same user, which could hint at the use of the case importer. You can be more accurate with this if you know the date on which the import was performed, as you could also filter the data in the export using date ranges.